# What does it mean "given a NFA and its accepted language L build the DFA that accepts L*"?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Supposing we have either a NFA or a DFA with accepted language $L$, what is $L^*$? And how can I build an automaton that accepts it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L^*$ is the [Kleene closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) of $L$. This is the language of all strings that can be made by taking a finite number of (not necessarily different) strings from $L$ and concatenating them.  More formally,

$$L^* = \{\varepsilon\}\cup\{w\in\Sigma^*\mid \exists k\geq 1\,\exists w_1, \dots, w_k\in L \text{ such that } w = w_1\cdot\dots\cdot w_k\}\,.$$

Or, if you prefer, for $k\geq 1$, let
$$L^k = \{w_1\cdot \dots \cdot w_k\mid w_1, \dots, w_k\in L\}$$
and then $L^* = \{\varepsilon\}\cup L^1 \cup L^2 \cup L^3 \cup\cdots\,$.

As for how to produce an automaton that accepts that, I suggest you think about it some more yourself, now that you know what it is you're trying to do. A hint would be to use nondeterminism to "guess" where the words $w_2, \dots, w_k$ begin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! What about adding a sink state to which all the final states are connected through a epsilon transition and then connect this sink to the initial state? In this way I should be able to concatenate all the accepted strings. Further, I could add a final state connected to the initial state through a epsilon transition in order to be able to accept epsilon.

Comment: @lelli That looks like it should work. Check all the details to make sure you've not missed anything. (I don't think you have but you should still check.)